# Targetting specific jquery element which have identical class names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several divs which are generating dynamically which share same class names, If I hover on parent(myDiv) need to trigger an event and on hover need to add a class to `myDiv`(child button) and once I clicked on parent div(myDiv) need to unbind hover action?

```
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="myBtn"></div>
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="myBtn"></div>
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="myBtn"></div>
</div>
```

Tried in the below way

```
$(document).on('click', '.myDiv', function() {
    //some task will goes here  
    $(this).unbind('hover');            
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.myBtn').css('background','#666666');
});
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I have added that please check once

Comment: doesn't your code do what you asked?

Comment: The code which I had written is not working, is there any solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1nm3omLe/3/) is the jsFiddle link.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myDiv', function() {
  //some task will goes here
  $(this).off();
});

$('.myDiv').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.myBtn').toggleClass('active');
});
```

CSS:

```
.myDiv {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.myBtn {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using $(document) because of some hierarchy issue for click, due to this hover function is not working properly and it is applying to all the divs not for the target one.

Comment: I see. I updated the JavaScript to use $(document). Now every '.myDiv' is given the hover attribute, and clicking it removes it.

Comment: Thanks for that, written in below way $(document).on('mouseenter', '.myDiv', function() {
    $(this).find('.myBtn').toggleClass('active');
  }); the problme here is that when hovering on another div clas is not toggling for the existing one.